# Android USB read/write is working only by reconnecting cable

Tags: java, android, usb

I am working with Java Eclips, galaxy tab 2 android 4.1.1

I have a device that is connected to the USB and I can write and read from/to it.

my problem is that I can read/write to the device only if I turn on the app by replugging the USB cable, if I close the app and try to switch it on by icon the USB is not reacting by read and write
while I try to connect to the USB I have no errors it seems like success but the write gets and exception : 
"ENODEV (No such device)"

dose some one can help?

Answer (score 0):

I know that there is already 2 years left since a question posted but I would like to post an answer anywhere.

You face with a well know Android USB bug

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=59667

What I do in this way is simple parse an error and display a Alert Dialog that it is necessary to unplug and plug USB cable.